# button chain remove previous class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, button, chain

I'm working on a code to change body background img. It works with buttons where I click on a button and change the img. When I click on first button it works, then I click on second button and also it works...but when I click again on first button it doesn't work.

I tried some code to remove the previous class but it doesn't work. I don't really too much about code :'(

Thanks. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  

        $('.button1').click(function(){
            $('body').addClass('fondonieve1').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
         });
          $('.button2').click(function(){
            $('body').addClass('fondonieve2').siblings().removeClass('active');
          });
          $('.button3').click(function(){
             $('body').addClass('fondootono1').siblings().removeClass('active');

        });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: You're going to need to use removeClass as well, to get rid of the classes added by prior button clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can removeClass again like this

```
$('body').addClass('fondonieve1').siblings().removeClass('active').removeClass('fondonieve2');
```

so you code should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  

        $('.button1').click(function(){
            $('body').addClass('fondonieve1').siblings().removeClass('active').removeClass('fondonieve2');
         });
          $('.button2').click(function(){
            $('body').addClass('fondonieve2').siblings().removeClass('active').removeClass('fondonieve1');
          });
          $('.button3').click(function(){
             $('body').addClass('fondootono1').siblings().removeClass('active').removeClass('fondonieve2');

        });
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code

CSS

```
 body {background-image: url(img/fondonieve1.gif);}
.fondonieve1{background-image: url(img/fondonieve1.gif);}
.fondonieve2{background-image: url(img/fondonieve2.gif);}
.fondootono1{background-image: url(img/fondootono1.gif);}
.fondootono2{background-image: url(img/fondootono2.gif);}
.fondoplanoclaro{background-image: none; background-color:#FFF;}
.fondoplanooscuro{background-image: none;background-color:#000;}
```

Script

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAABZGjjDpjmjbzLaNWBpdrWhRYfwzT-VuwidSQZM_JU-MUSrbEShR1efDdxuqpWPsjsfs1V_59FUTrxg" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){  

            $('.button1').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondonieve1').removeClass('fondonieve2 fondootono1 fondootono2 fondoplanoclaro fondoplanooscuro'); 
             });
          $('.button2').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondonieve2').removeClass('fondonieve1 fondootono1 fondootono2 fondoplanoclaro fondoplanooscuro'); 
             });
          $('.button3').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondootono1').removeClass('fondonieve2 fondonieve1 fondootono2 fondoplanoclaro fondoplanooscuro'); 
             });
          $('.button4').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondootono2').removeClass('fondonieve2 fondootono1 fondonieve1 fondoplanoclaro fondoplanooscuro'); 
             });
          $('.button5').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondoplanoclaro').removeClass('fondonieve2 fondootono1 fondootono2 fondonieve1 fondoplanooscuro'); 
             });
          $('.button6').click(function(){
                $('body').addClass('fondoplanooscuro').removeClass('fondonieve2 fondootono1 fondootono2 fondoplanoclaro fondonieve1'); 
             });

            });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<button class="button1">Nieve1</button>
<button class="button2">Nieve2</button>
<button class="button3">Otoño1</button>
<button class="button4">Otoño2</button>
<button class="button5">Claro</button>
<button class="button6">Oscuro</button>
```